# Multi Dimensional Array - Introduction to recursion / Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion

I'm trying to learn recursion in javascript but I'm litteraly lost. In theory, it's easy, Recursion is simply when a function calls itself.

```
function factorial(x) {
  if (x < 0) return;
  if (x === 0) return 1;
  return x * factorial(x - 1);
}
factorial(3);
```

If I have to iterate through a multidimensional array. How can I apply recursive function to do that?
I would like manipulate these multidimensial arrays without writing multi loops.

```
for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
       for (let k = 0; k < points.length; k++) {
            for (let l = 0; l < points.length; l++) {
                 ...
        }
    }
}

let points = ([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

I think Recursive function can solve by the easiest manner this problem by dividing the iteration of the first array and call the same function by itself until the end of the sub arrays.

Can you explain me how to do that?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I would like to sort these arrays (max , min, max[0] of each arrays, etc..)

Comment: You want to sort each of the inner array in `points`? - 1 for-loop should do that. Why do you need to 4 nested for-loop? Can you please share your desire output from the `points` example?

Comment: OK. Understood. So you think recursive function is not the shorter way to manipulate multi dimensional array? Thank for you advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can write recursion for iterating multidimensional array something like this.

```js
var points = [[1, 2], 3, [4, 3], [10, 50], [98, 100]];

    function recursion(array, length = 0) {
        if (array.length === length) return 0;

        if (Array.isArray(array[length])) {
            recursion(array[length]);
        }
        console.log(array[length]);

        recursion(array, length + 1);
    }
    
    recursion(points);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **using for-in loop**

```
let points = ([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
for (arr in points){
    for(subarr in arr){
        .........
    }
}
```

> **using for loop**

```
let points = ([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
for (let i=0; i<points.length;i++){
    for(let j=0; j<points[i].length;j++){
        .........
    }
}
```