# How to add or update items in this multidimensional JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm

Let's say we have some houses represented as JSON. Something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "code": "1",
        "name": "Smith's",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "",
                "code": "11",
                "name": "Kitchen",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "",
                        "code": "111",
                        "name": "Sink",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "",
                "code": "12",
                "name": "Living Room",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "",
                        "code": "121",
                        "name": "Television",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "",
                                "code": "1211",
                                "name": "Panel buttons",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "",
                                        "code": "12111",
                                        "name": "Power button",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "",
                                        "code": "12112",
                                        "name": "Colors adjust button",
                                        "children": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "",
                                "code": "1221",
                                "name": "Screen",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "code": "2",
        "name": "Taylor's",
        "children": [
            // Here goes all house places and items like the example above
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "code": "1",
        "name": "Wilson's",
        "children": [
            // Here goes all house places and items like the example above
        ]
    }
]
```

Take notice that the "code" property, found in each item, is something to represent the "path" until that item, carrying its parents "code" property concatenated with its own position by incremental order. So the code "11" means house 1 and child 1. And 212 would be house 2, child 1, child 2. Also take notice that all items follow the same type. In other words, every item has a children that follows its own type. So, it could be infinite.

Now, I'd like to maintain these structure. Adding items, updating items and so on. Let's say we want to add a carpet in Smith's living room. We would go deep in the structure 2 levels, which are Smith's house (index 0 of the array) and living room (index 1 of the children array). And then add a carpet.

The problem is it won't be 2 levels in all cases. What if I wanted to add a bathroom? It would be level 1, alongside with kitchen in living room (the first children). What if I'd like to add a microwave in the kitchen and add to it buttons, display, etc?

I think I'm a recursive scenario where I have to visit all items and, if it is the one I'm looking to reach at, add/updated it.

[I've tried following this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54547909/multi-dimensional-array-introduction-to-recursion-javascript)

I couldn't figure it out how to bring it to my case. though.

I appreciate if your contribution is in JavaScript, but feel free to represent it in other language in case you are better in other language =).

Comment: What happens to your IDs when you get to 10 or more children.  If this json structure gets "Too big", it will be very slow to add say a carpet compared to a more traditional database.

Comment: Can you add a specific question? If you want to add a bathroom you go to the level where the other rooms are. Are you asking how to find out which one the room level is? Or how to find an item by name?

Comment: So the input to your function would be `func(tree, item, parent_code)`?

Comment: Also, how exactly do you plan to use this object (which is what you get once the JSON is parsed)? Is it supposed to act like a database? Is this for a game? What's the point of all this?

Comment: @James I'm trying to save it in NoSQL database as a JSON structure. When I register a new father register, I think it will add an ID only in the father.

Comment: @ChrisG yes, I already added a specific question: "What if I wanted to add a bathroom? It would be level 1, alongside with kitchen in living room (the first children). What if I'd like to add a microwave in the kitchen and add to it buttons, display, etc?" I'd like to add/updated items in it.

Comment: @ITgoldman thanks, it seems your suggestion would be a recursion, right?

Comment: @ChrisG it is supposed to be NoSQL registers.

Comment: This is a tree structure with identical nodes. I'd store it in mongodb, i.e. each node is a document. When you want to add a new node, you create it, then add it to the supposed parent node's children. You can find a node by name, provided it is unique. Still, how are you going to use this exactly? And what is a "NoSQL register"?

Comment: @ChrisG it is a checklist for cleaning inspection. Not only for houses. The example I gave was to simplify. The customer requires infinite nodes possibility. It doesn't mean they will reach many levels down. I believe 4 is the maximum. And yes my MongoDB is already up and working just like you mentioned. The "NoSQL register" is the document you also mentioned. I don't know if all NoSQL databases call them "documents" so I used the term "register". It didn't work, it seems. The question already has an answer now and I'm studying it.

Comment: Right. The answer is for updating a nested array of objects but it'll work differently with mongodb or another noSQL solution.

Comment: @ChrisG It doesn't matter the database, what my purpose is or what happens if the levels get too deep down like I've been questioned since then. I gave the problem and it has all that is needed to be solved. Two people kindly solved it.

Comment: No, because if that data structure is stored in a DB, accessing and updating a node works very differently. The database part very much does matter here and your question alone is not enough to give a useful answer (see also here: [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/))

Comment: @ChrisG I had an answer down below totally based on what my question was created. So you probably didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed some questions, like for instance what happens if you have more than 10 items as child and why do you need it?
And what happens if you remove any item on any level? will you recursively start updating all codes?

Nevertheless I gave it a go. In essence what I do in the code is first search for the parent (example: Kitchen) where you want to add it to and then add the new child item (example: Carpet) to it.

The search is a typical recursive search.
The child addition is a typical addition to an array.
For argument's sake I assumed that the fields code always exist and that children is always an array.

```
// Actual code is underneath the declaration of this array
let houseList = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "code": "1",
        "name": "Smith's",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "",
                "code": "11",
                "name": "Kitchen",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "",
                        "code": "111",
                        "name": "Sink",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "",
                "code": "12",
                "name": "Living Room",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "",
                        "code": "121",
                        "name": "Television",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "",
                                "code": "1211",
                                "name": "Panel buttons",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "",
                                        "code": "12111",
                                        "name": "Power button",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "",
                                        "code": "12112",
                                        "name": "Colors adjust button",
                                        "children": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "",
                                "code": "1221",
                                "name": "Screen",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "code": "2",
        "name": "Taylor's",
        "children": [
            // Here goes all house places and items like the example above
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "code": "1",
        "name": "Wilson's",
        "children": [
            // Here goes all house places and items like the example above
        ]
    }
]

addChild(houseList,"11",{name:"Carpet" });
addChild(houseList,"1211",{name: "Volume Up Button"});
addChild(houseList,"1211",{name: "Volume Down Button"});
console.log('new houselist', houseList);

// child is just what you want to add and the parentCode refers to where you want to add it to
function addChild(houseList, parentCode, child) {
    let parent = findInHouseList(houseList,parentCode,child);
  let amountOfChildren = parent.children.length;
  let newCodeName = parentCode +""+ (amountOfChildren+1);
  child = {...{id: "", code: newCodeName, children: []}, ...child};
  console.log('adding child ', child);
  
  parent.children = [...parent.children, child];
}

function findInHouseList(houseList,code) {
    for (let house of houseList) {
    
    let foundElement = findElement(house,code);
    if ( foundElement)
        return foundElement;
  }
}

function findElement(currentElement, code) {
    if ( currentElement.code === code)
    return currentElement;
    
  if (currentElement.children?.length > 0)
    {
        for (let child of currentElement.children) {
        let foundElement = findElement(child,code);
        if ( foundElement)
            return foundElement;
      }
    }
  
  return null;
}
```

I decided to let the code manage the code names for new children. It seems the easiest.

Comment: Sorry my late mr. I'm really impressed on how fast your answer was. I took some time to study your code before answering back and it makes sense. I appreciate that besides simply asking the purpose of my code, you actually did something. That's so noble. Thank you so much. I will implement it and I kindly ask you if I could contact you here again in case I miss something (I hope not!). Also I'd like to ask if, in your perspective, I could refactor the findInHouseList and findElement functions, turning them only one function. They appear to do the same logic. Thanks again! Best wishes! =)

Comment: Oh and I think it's fair answering your questions since you have helped me. It is a cleaning inspection logic. They will carry a "clean" and "not clean" options. It's going to be used not only for houses. It was just an example. I don't think the children nodes will reach 10 levels, although the code needs to allow it. What happens if any item is removed? Well that means that the item was, let's say phisically removed too. So in my scenario, the kitchen will always be there and it will always have a sink.

Comment: If it can contain more than 10 levels you need to have a delimiter because otherwise what does this code ="111" mean. Is this the 11th element with 1 child, or is this the 1st element with 1 child and 1 subchild ?
To solve this add a delimiter like ":"
Then you will have code ="11:1" or code ="1:1:1"

To answer your other question: findInHouseList  and findElement are comparable, but the trick is that findInHouseList works for an array and findElement for a single node. You could resolve this by just having a tree with only one startnode instead of having an array of nodes as a start.

Comment: Sorry my late. About the "111", it is the second scenario you mentioned, which means, first father, first son, first grandson. And yes I have implemented a delimiter like "1-1-1". And thank you for your explanation about the logic for the array e the other for the single node.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is updating a JSON value at a dynamic path.

This function will append a child to the item which holds the specified code.
You may add conditions to check if the item at the code is defined

```
function appendChild(houses, code, item) {
    let path = code.split('')
    let o = houses

    for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        let n = path[i] - 1
        o = o[n]["children"]
    }

    o.push(item)

    return houses
}
```

However, you should start your code indexes at 0 and storing them inside the JSON is useless since they are simply the path to reach the item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eole_. I miss the recursion in your code. Isn't apprendChild suppose to call itself somewhere?

Comment: My bad, there's no recursion is this code actually (you could still do it using recursion though). I'll edit.